# Typescript import classes with same name causes override

Tags: angular, typescript

Using Angular 5 I want to import two classes with the same name and methods but in different path.

```
import { Product as product1 } from '../app/file1'
import { Product as product2 } from '../app/file2'
```

The problem is when I tried to call something on product1.getInfo() the code from product2.getInfo() got executed.

When I removed the import of product2 the product1.getInfo() was executed normally.

I can't understand why and what is the solution.

Is this issue related on how typescript merge the classes with same names?
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html

Can anyone help me with this please?

Thanks in advance

Comment: There is no problem with the above code, do you have a repo?

Comment: Not sure if that is a problem at all, look at the similar demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5-tutorial-4kgsmn

Comment: Could you update your question on how both Product type data-structures look like and how you are creating an object of each one